# double sort in xslt on two different fields

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to sort my xml file on two fieds:
identifier and impact.
I would like to order the elements by identifier, EXCEPT for the elements that have a XX product which must appear last.

My xml file is

```
<evolutionlist>
<date>
    <object>
        <identifier>id5</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>AA</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
    <object>
        <identifier>id2</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>XX</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
    <object>
        <identifier>id4</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>BB</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
   <object>
        <identifier>id3</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>XX</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
    <object>
        <identifier>id1</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>CC</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
 </date>
 </evolutionlist>
```

The expceted result would be:

```
<evolutionlist>
<date>
    <object>
        <identifier>id1</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>CC</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
    <object>
        <identifier>id4</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>BB</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
    <object>
        <identifier>id5</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>AA</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
   <object>
        <identifier>id2</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>XX</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
    <object>
        <identifier>id3</identifier>
        <impact>
            <product>XX</produit>
        </impact>
    </objet>
 </date>
 </evolutionlist>
```

my xslt code (does not work though) is

```
<xsl:for-each  select="//date">
   <tr>
  <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
  </td>
   </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="./object">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="impact/produit = 'XX'">
            <xsl:sort select="impact/produit" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sort select="identifiant"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>

        ...
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a `<xsl:sort>` in the beginning of a `<xsl:for-each>` or `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, not in a `<choose>` block.

You are using sort to order the `XX`, so *I will assume* that's OK in your scenario (e.g.: you don't have a product named `ZZ`, which would be placed after the `XX`). If that's not the case, you shouldn't use `sort` for that rule, but a template which matches the `XX` contents and places them at the end.

This stylesheet produces the results you expect using the `sort` rules you have in your original stylesheet (ordering by id and product strings). I moved the selection rules into an XPath predicate, and used templates instead of nested `for-each` nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="date">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="object">
                <xsl:sort select="impact/product[. = 'XX']" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="identifier"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can try it out in this **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHSX)**

**UPDATE** In the case that you don't actually want to *order* the `XX` products, but place them at the end, always, you can filter those elements and apply their templates after processing the other elements. This other stylesheet does that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="date">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="object[not(impact[product = 'XX'])]">
            <xsl:sort select="identifier"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="object[impact[product = 'XX']]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's another **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpE)** with this example.

Comment: thanks for the help, it is more clear, unfortunately, I can have ZZ produtcs, which muste be sorted according to their id, only the XX products must appear at the end, sorry I was not precise enough

Comment: that is why I used the "when" condition

Comment: You don't need `when`. You can select with templates and predicates, which is also more efficient. I added a solution placing the `XX` elements at the end.

Comment: thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I need, the solution is very clear !

Comment: and thanks for the XSLT Fiddle tip ! I did not know it !